# Multiple Rows in Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to implement the following design. I have initially started with `ListView` but I could not able to handle it. Is it ok to add multiple rows with `Textview` and `EditText` or is there a better way of handling it?

[image]

---

**First Approach**

Here is my initial attempt to use `ListView`.

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.SettingsFragment, container, false);
   myItems1.Add ("Username");
   myItems1.Add ("Password");
    
   myListView1 = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView7);
   myListView1.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
   myListView1.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter (Activity, global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, myItems1);
   return view;
}
```

---

**Second Approach**

Here is my initial attempt of using `TableLayout`

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text13"
                android:text="Password:"
                android:editable="false"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:background="#000000" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText14"
                android:text="lifedemo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:editable="true"
                android:background="#000000" />
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can you use a TableLayout in xamarin?

Comment: Yes you can use `TableLayout`.

Comment: can you paste  the initial code for listView if there is a correction to make. list view may be better.

Comment: Then I think it will suite your needs. It can handle the aligning of elements in columns and it is naturally divided by rows. It is definitely an option. You can also stick to the RelativeLayout and use rules to position your elements.

Comment: @Ibukun, how you are going to handle `textview` and `edittext` and even `toggle` button in the `listview`? I have added my `listView` initial attempt code

Comment: @DanailAlexiev, please see my updated code and question with `TableLayout`

Comment: @Andrea, looks good. What exactly is your problem?